# Let $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ be such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le M|x-y|^\alpha$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Problem**

Let $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ be such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le M|x-y|^\alpha$ for some $M>0, \alpha>1$ and for all $x,y\in \Bbb R$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

---

**Attempt**

If $f$ is not constant, then there exists $x,y$ such that $x\neq y\Rightarrow f(x)\neq f(y)$. Then, $0<|f(x)-f(y)|$. Between any two distinct real numbers, we can always find a real number. Let's pick a real number between $0$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|$, and call that number $c$. 
Then, $0<c<|f(x)-f(y)|$.

Now let's look at $|x-y|$, which is also greater than $0$. For our $c$, no matter what positive number we have picked, and no matter how large $|x-y|$ is, it is possible to pick $M>0$ arbitrarily close to $0$ and $\alpha>1$ arbitrarily close to $1$ so that

\begin{align*}\sqrt[\alpha] {c\over M}>|x-y|&\Rightarrow M|x-y|^\alpha <c<|f(x)-f(y)|\\&\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|>M|x-y|^\alpha\end{align*}

But, the problem states that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le M|x-y|^\alpha$, so the only way to meet this condition is if $f(x)=f(y)$ regardless of our choice of $x,y$. If $f(x)=f(y)$ regardless of our choice of $x,y$, then this means that $f$ is constant.

**End of Attempt**

---

To be honest, I don't have a clue if I'm even doing anything correctly... I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: The problem stipulates an inequality for *some* $M$ and $\alpha$, not for *all* $M$ and $\alpha$, so you don't get to *pick* arbitrary values for $M$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: For the record: the keyword here is [$\alpha$-Hölder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition).

Comment: Can you do with "these conditions imply $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$" ?

Comment: In this problem M and $\alpha$ are fixed. You cannot select them as you are doing in this problem. Instead try dividing your given inequality by $|x-y|$ and note what is left over on the right hand side since $\alpha$ is greater than 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a $ be an arbitrary real.

for $x\ne a $,
$$|f (x)-f (a)|\le M|x-a|^\alpha $$
and

$$\frac {|f (x)-f (a)|}{|x-a|}\le M |x-a|^\beta $$
with $$\beta =\alpha-1>0$$

thus if $x $ goes to $a ,$

$f (x)-f (a) $ goes to zero and

$\frac {f (x)-f (a)}{x-a} $ goes to zero.

this means that $f $ is continuous at $a $ and differentiable at $a $ with $$f'(a)=0$$

You can finish.

Comment: Is the fact that $\beta>0$ important? If so, why?

Comment: @orchid if not $|x-a|^beta $ will not go to zero.

Comment: @orchid, yes the fact that $\beta = \alpha - 1 > 0$ is essential in this problem. If $\beta < 0$ then the quantity on the left, $|f(x)-f(a)|/|x-a|$ would not be constained and could grow arbitrarily large as $x$ approaches $a$. If $\beta = 0$, then the right hand side would become $M$, and though your problem is constrained, it still wouldn't go to zero. With $\beta = 0$, your function might not be differentiable.

With any $\alpha > 0$, you gain continuity. With $\alpha > 1$ you gain differentiability.

Comment: Haha, I asked too quickly, because I meant if something like $\beta>1$ instead of $\beta>0$ would be okay, without realizing that $\beta>1>0\Rightarrow \beta>0$. I should just go to sleep...

Answer (score 6):

Since $x\neq y\Longrightarrow\left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right|\leqslant M|x-y|^{\alpha-1}$ and since $\alpha-1>0$, $(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):f'(x)=0.$ Therefore, $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach: Let $x>0.$ Then for any $n\in \mathbb N,$

$$|f(x)-f(0)| = |\sum_{k=1}^{n}[f(kx/n) - f((k-1)x/n]| \le \sum_{k=1}^{n}|f(kx/n) - f((k-1)x/n)| $$ $$\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}M|x/n|^\alpha \le n M \frac{1}{n^\alpha}= \frac{M}{n^{\alpha-1}}. $$

Since $\alpha - 1 > 0,$ the expression on the right $\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$ Therefore $f(x)-f(0)=0,$ proving $f$ is constant on $[0,\infty).$ For $x<0$ just consider $f(-x).$